# Python generator expression Twitter

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I am kinda new to working with json and python and I am stuck on the parsing the data in js to generate an expression.  I would really appreciate anyone suggestions on the best path to take.

Here is the Data I am working with

{"statuses":[{"metadata":{"result_type":"recent","iso_language_code":"en"},"created_at":"Fri Dec 06 15:06:44 +0000 2013","id":408975801577926656,"id_str":"408975801577926656","text":"RT @jk636575: @GhanaNudes contact me if you want to swing\njk636575@gmail.com","user":{"id":974873810,"id_str":"974873810","name":"Gh Nudes","screen_name":"GhanaNudes","location"

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    ts = TwitterSearch()
    response, data = ts.search('@gmail.com', result_type='recent')
    js = json.loads(data)

    messages = ([data_items] for msg in js)
```

I need to parse the content in js and turn it into a generator expression so that I only write:  Created_at , text , user:{is

Comment: What does your current code do? How is that wrong? What do you want it to do? This question is unclear at best.

Comment: I can answer, but.. Won't. Help. You. Searching. For. Porn.

Comment: He is trying to complete my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414701/twitter-python-json-to-csv/20415034?noredirect=1#comment30493467_20415034

Comment: yes, i am not trying to look for porn but that particular piece of the data is quite funny.  I am actually trying to locate people who mention their email address in a public forum and associate it to a twitter ID

Comment: Yes it is to complete the question Hugh helped with prior in the evening  stackoverflow.com/questions/20414701/twitter-python-json-to-csv/…

Comment: @user2748540 Just read that. Loled. That's rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Twitter search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) docs,

```
messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['txt'], msg['user']['id']] for msg in js['statuses'])
```

Note that I have updated [my answer to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414701/twitter-python-json-to-csv/20415034#20415034) to include this.

**Edit:** It might be a bit safer to replace `in js['statuses']` with `in js.get('statuses', [])`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help on this topic