# How do I download a .csv file I created in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I've created a .csv file using this code in a Python shell (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872153/2532070):

```
mylist = ['''list_of_strings''']

import csv

with open('filename', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(mylist)
```

How do I then download the 'myfile' csv to my machine so I can email it as a .csv attachment? Thanks!

Comment: what machine do you think the file went to?  :)  it'll be wherever you ran the python shell from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is really the exact code that you ran, then the file is named `filename` (with no extension) and is in the folder that you were in when you ran the script (probably the same folder the script file itself is stored in).  The file will *not* be called `myfile`, that's just an identifier in the script.

Probably what you *wanted* to do was

```
 with open('your_data_in_here.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
```

which would create a file called `your_data_in_here.csv` in the current working folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean *download*, I expect you want to *read* the csv you've just created. For this we'll use [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('filename', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Comment: I actually want to download it so that I can email to someone using Excel who specifically wants it as a .csv file.

Comment: Well, then what you have created is in fact a csv file. If you save it with the .csv extension and email it to someone with Excel, they'll be able to open it.

Comment: Thanks - I don't understand, where is said file? It's on my machine somewhere?

Comment: If you run a script which writes a csv file and it's called 'filename' or 'filename.csv' then it should be in the same directory as the script you've executed.

Comment: Got it, thank you, so it automatically saves into the directory from which I ran the shell.