# Python 3.4 writing a list to a csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am having trouble writing a list to a csv.  My current code writes the list (comprised of strings) to the file with spaces between each character.  This is what I'm working with, the problem is most likely in the last 3 or 4 lines:

```
import csv
import sys
import collections

c1 = set()
c2 = set()
c3 = set()

new=(r'file')
old=(r'file2')

with open(new, 'r') as newfile:
    newreader = csv.reader(newfile, delimiter=(','))
    for row in newreader:
        c1.add(row[0])

with open(old, 'r') as oldfile:
    oldreader = csv.reader(oldfile, delimiter=(','))
    for row in oldreader:
        c2.add(row[0])

c3=c2-c1
c1=c2|c3
print(c1)
print(c2)
print(c3)

with open (r'csv1.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_file:
    write=csv.writer(write_file, delimiter=' ')

    write.writerows(list(c1))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have input and desired output?

Comment: `c1` is **not a list**, nor is it a list of lists. You have **sets** here.

Comment: you should show us the print ... especially the c1 print ...

Comment: I want to write the set c1 to the file csv1.

Comment: One row per string in the set, or one column per string all on one line?

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve with these sets? `c2 - c1` produces all elements in `c2` that are not in `c1`. You then create the union between `c2` and `c3`, but *`c3` only contains elements **already** in `c2`*.

Comment: I also have been trying write.writerows(list(c1))i should update that

Comment: I mainly wanted to add everything in c2 that isn't in c1 to c1.  I know I can do that faster but that's just what I have down and it computes.

Comment: @RonTheBear: Have you considered that `c1` could be empty?

Comment: @RonTheBear: and you need a list of lists to have `writerows()` work; you'd have to do `write.writerows([r] for r in c1)` here.

Comment: List of lists worked.  Thanks @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writer.writerows()` (plural, with `s`), takes a *sequence of sequences*; each nested sequence is a row with columns.

Your set on the other hand, is not such a nested structure. Produce one with a generator expression:

```
with open (r'csv1.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_file:
    write=csv.writer(write_file)
    write.writerows([r] for r in c1)
```

This produces lists with one column for each row. Since there is just the one column, it doesn't matter what you set the delimiter to.