# create csv file from text using python

Tags: python, list, csv, text

i have a list of data like

Name\n
Designations
Mobile
Email
Adiba
Chairman
+880123456
adiba@gmail.com
delim
Asst Prof
+8801734534
delim@gmail.com
mali
Asst Prof
+88013254534
mali@gmail.com

now i want to put this in csv file like this farmat.

```
Name    Designations    Mobile             Email
Adiba   Chairman        +880123456      adiba@gmail.com
delim   Asst Prof       +880173453      delim@gmail.com
mali    Asst Prof       +88013254534    mali@gmail.com
```

how can i separate 4 part using python language?

Comment: OK. Do you have a question?

Comment: It might be good to say the format of your data.  Is it in a data.frame?   Four separate lists?

Comment: *i have a list of data* - show the actual list contents

Comment: list of data::::

Name
Designations
Mobile
 Emai
 Adiba 
Chairman 
+880123456 
adiba@gmail.com 
delim 
Asst Prof 
+8801734534 
delim@gmail.com 
mali 
Asst 
Prof +88013254534 
mali@gmail.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a .csv file with values from a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a list of lists/tuples where in each tuples there are 4 parts - Name, Designation, Phone and Email. So, you can simply do this -

```
csvfile =  open("hello.csv", "w", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerows(list_to_write)
csvfile.close()
```

Make sure you close the file when you are done.

**EDIT**

If you are scrapping from a webpage then after getting the values of Name, Designation, Phone and Email make a tuple and then append it to the list.

```
list_to_write = []
append_it = (Name, Designation, Phone, Email)
list_to_write.append(append_it)
```

While writing to csv file be careful about csv.writerow(). Use csv.writerows(), it will write all the rows you have in your list and csv.writerow() will write only the 1st row.

Comment: csv file read/write kora ami chai nai .
chaisi kemne ogula alada kormu.

Comment: Then edit your question and clarify what you actually want.