# Parsing child nodes from JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse specific child nodes from a JSON file using Python.

I know similar questions have been asked and answered before, but I simply haven't been able to translate those solutions to my own problem (disclaimer: I'm not a developer).

This is the beginning of my JSON file (each new "entry" starts at "_index"):

```
{
"took": 83,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 713628,
    "max_score": 1.3753585,
    "hits": [{
        "_index": "offentliggoerelser-prod-20161006",
        "_type": "offentliggoerelse",
        "_id": "urn:ofk:oid:5135592",
        "_score": 1.3753585,
        "_source": {
            "cvrNummer": 89986915,
            "indlaesningsId": "AUzWhUXw3pscZq1LGK_z",
            "sidstOpdateret": "2015-04-20T10:53:09.154Z",
            "omgoerelse": false,
            "regNummer": null,
            "offentliggoerelsestype": "regnskab",
            "regnskab": {
                "regnskabsperiode": {
                    "startDato": "2014-01-01",
                    "slutDato": "2014-12-31"
                }
            },
            "indlaesningsTidspunkt": "2015-04-20T11:10:53.529Z",
            "sagsNummer": "X15-AA-66-TA",
            "dokumenter": [{
                "dokumentUrl": "http://regnskaber.virk.dk/51968998/ZG9rdW1lbnRsYWdlcjovLzAzLzdlL2I5L2U2LzlkLzIxN2EtNDA1OC04Yjg0LTAwZGJlNzUwMjU3Yw.pdf",
                "dokumentMimeType": "application/pdf",
                "dokumentType": "AARSRAPPORT"
            }, {
                "dokumentUrl": "http://regnskaber.virk.dk/51968998/ZG9rdW1lbnRsYWdlcjovLzAzLzk0LzNlL2RjL2Q4L2I1NjUtNGJjZC05NzJmLTYyMmE4ZTczYWVhNg.xhtml",
                "dokumentMimeType": "application/xhtml+xml",
                "dokumentType": "AARSRAPPORT"
            }, {
                "dokumentUrl": "http://regnskaber.virk.dk/51968998/ZG9rdW1lbnRsYWdlcjovLzAzLzc5LzM3LzUwLzMxL2NjZWQtNDdiNi1hY2E1LTgxY2EyYjRmOGYzMw.xml",
                "dokumentMimeType": "application/xml",
                "dokumentType": "AARSRAPPORT"
            }],
            "offentliggoerelsesTidspunkt": "2015-04-20T10:53:09.075Z"
        }
    },
```

More specifically, I'm trying to extract all "dokumentUrl" where "dokumentMimeType" is equal to "application/xhtml+xml".

When I use something simple like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('output.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['dokumenter'][1]['dokumentUrl'])
```

I get the first URL that matches my criteria. But how do I create a list of all URLs (all 713.628 of them) from the file with the criteria mentioned above and export it to a CSV file?

I should probably mention that my end goal is to create a program that can loop scrape my list of URLs (I'll save that for another post!).

Comment: `data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['dokumenter']` returns a list that you can iterate through, so something like `for item in data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['dokumenter']: print item['dokumentUrl']`. Does that do what you want to do (except with the check `item['dokumentMimeType'] == "application/xhtml+xml"` before printing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I am understand this right, and @roganjosh has a similar idea. You can loop through the specific parts with contain lists of useful things. So, we can do something like:

```
myURL = []
hits = data['hits']['hits']
for hit in hits:
    // Making the assumption here that you want all of the URLs associated with a given document
    document = hit['_source']['dokumenter']
    for url in document:
        if url['dokumentMimeType'] == "application/xhtml+xml":
            myURL.append(url['dokumentUrl'])
```

Again, I am hoping that I understand your JSON schema enough that this does what you want it to. At least it should get you close.

Also just saw another part of your question regarding [CSV outputting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list).

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixes my problem. And thank you for the link to CSV outputting. I got it to write my output to a CSV file, but I'm having some trouble getting it to write the URLs in a single column, instead of a single row. Does this have something to do with my output or does the writer have a built in function to transpose the data?

Comment: Nevermind. Found a solution. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this quick enough. Hope you got your solution functioning!