# What is the value of X and y from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am  working on hepatitis dataset from UCI repository.
It has imbalanced class.
Class Distribution:
     DIE: 32
    LIVE: 123
 I am trying to use the ADASYN oversampling method to balance the class.

In the examples they have generated a dataset and passed it to ADASYN.
Can someone explain me in that format the value of x and y should be based on the dataset?

I am referring to the example from below link.

https://561-36019880-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/ubuntu/imbalanced-learn/doc/_build/html/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.ADASYN.html#imblearn.over_sampling.ADASYN

Please help me in splitting the dataset as X and Y value as required to pass to ADASYN

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But this might help:

X - 2D matrix where rows are examples and columns are your features
Y - is your response, for example, a 1D vector of `True` (for class LIVE) and `False` (for class DIE).

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN
# Apply the random over-sampling
ada = ADASYN()
X_resampled, y_resampled = ada.fit_sample(X, y)
```

`X_resampled` and `y_resampled` now include your original data plus the resampled data. Looking at `y_resampled` you should observe an equal number of labels for each class.

For your reference:

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/examples/over-sampling/plot_adasyn.py

Comment: How do we split the dataset as x and y? should X be the columns other than the class label column and y be the class label column??

Comment: After the split up how do we create a new csv with the balanced dataset.

Comment: if you are using `pandas` to manage your data then you can use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or you can see [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list) on StackOverflow for creating CSV from `python lists`.