# Python : Convert Integers into a Count (i.e. 3 --> 1,2,3)

Tags: python, regex, backreference, capturing-group, capture-group

This might be more information than necessary to explain my question, but I am trying to combine 2 scripts (I wrote for other uses) together to do the following.

TargetString (input_file) `4FOO` `2BAR`

Result (output_file) `1FOO` `2FOO` `3FOO` `4FOO` `1BAR` `2BAR`

My first script finds the pattern and copies to file_2

```
pattern = "\d[A-Za-z]{3}"
matches = re.findall(pattern, input_file.read())
f1.write('\n'.join(matches))
```

My second script opens the output_file and, using re.sub, replaces and alters the target string(s) using capturing groups and back-references. But I am stuck here on how to turn i.e. `3` into `1` `2` `3`.

Any ideas?

Comment: check [python range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: `for` and `range` will do this nicely.  Where are you stuck in writing a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple example doesn't need to use regular expression, but if you want to use `re` anyway, here's example (note: you have minor error in your pattern, should be `A-Z`, not `A-A`):

```
text_input = '4FOO 2BAR'

import re

matches = re.findall(r"(\d)([A-Za-z]{3})", text_input)

for (count, what) in matches:
    for i in range(1, int(count)+1):
        print(f'{i}{what}', end=' ')

print()
```

Prints:

```
1FOO 2FOO 3FOO 4FOO 1BAR 2BAR
```

Note: If you want to support multiple digits, you can use `(\d+)` - note the `+` sign.

Comment: You could generalise this to `(\d)+` to support multi-digit numbers.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, you have right. I put a note to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your numbers are between 1 and 9, without regex, you can use a list comprehension with f-strings (Python 3.6+):

```
L = ['4FOO', '2BAR']
res = [f'{j}{i[1:]}' for i in L for j in range(1, int(i[0])+1)]

['1FOO', '2FOO', '3FOO', '4FOO', '1BAR', '2BAR']
```

Reading and writing to CSV files are covered elsewhere: [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list), [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list).

More generalised, to account for numbers greater than 9, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

L = ['4FOO', '10BAR']

def make_var(x, int_flag):
    return int(''.join(x)) if int_flag else ''.join(x)

vals = ((make_var(b, a) for a, b in groupby(i, str.isdigit)) for i in L)

res = [f'{j}{k}' for num, k in vals for j in range(1, num+1)]

print(res)

['1FOO', '2FOO', '3FOO', '4FOO', '1BAR', '2BAR', '3BAR', '4BAR',
 '5BAR', '6BAR', '7BAR', '8BAR', '9BAR', '10BAR']
```

Comment: What about `10Foo`? (Update: Did not see the clarification in last line)

Comment: `Assumes your numbers are between 1 and 9.`. I'd like more clarity from OP to see whether this is actually a problem.

Comment: Granted, given OP's examples this is perfectly fine. However, the first line could be understood as "you do not need regex, but only if you have Python 3.6+".

Comment: @jpp thank you! this gives me an idea on how to approach, i was getting tunneled into what I already had.. the integers go into double digits so I would need to adjust to go beyond 1-9

Comment: @physlexic, I've updated for a more generalized solution.