# How do I get my python output into a csv or excel file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
for i in range(len(H)):
            S=Y[1:,(0,1,m)]  # change 2=> 2:m
            S=S[S[0:,0] ==HN[k]]
            S=S[S[0:,1] ==H[i]]
            S=S[S[0:,2]!=''] #
            S=S[0:,2]  #
            for j in range(len(S)):
                print(HN[k],H[i],S[j],H[j]*H[I])
```

This prints output of almost 900-1000 rows on my jupyter notebook. However I want output to be directly a `csv` or `xls` file. So that I don't have to copy or paste, would also save me time if rows increases of my data.

Comment: There is a [`csv` module in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Before the loop: `fileDesc = open('fileName.csv','w')`.

Comment: During the loop: `fileDesc.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(HN[k],H[i],S[j],H[j]*H[I]))`.

Comment: After the loop: `fileDesc.close()`.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks and where will this output(filename.csv) be saved ?

Comment: I believe that in `sys.path[0]` or `sys.path[1]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a .csv file with values from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @goodvibration just one more question, I also want header column named in my file, how do we write them before loop.

Comment: `fileDesc.write('header1,header2,header3,header4\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following.

- Open the file with csv.writer
- write row wise the data in the writer

```golang
import csv

...

writer = csv.writer(open("/path/to/my/csv/file", 'w'))
for i in range(len(H)):
    S=Y[1:,(0,1,m)]  # change 2=> 2:m
    S=S[S[0:,0] ==HN[k]]
    S=S[S[0:,1] ==H[i]]
    S=S[S[0:,2]!=''] #
    S=S[0:,2]  #

    for j in range(len(S)):
        writer.writerow(HN[k], H[i], S[j], H[j]*H[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import csv

csvFile = open('example.csv', 'w')

with csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    for i in range(len(H)):
        S=Y[1:,(0,1,m)]
        S=S[S[0:,0] ==HN[k]]
        S=S[S[0:,1] ==H[i]]
        S=S[S[0:,2]!=''] #
        S=S[0:,2]  #
        for j in range(len(S)):
            writer.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(HN[k],H[i],S[j],H[j]*H[I]))
```