# Pandas how to save a list to csv

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a list in pandas and I want to write it to a csv file where each element is a new row.

```
    list3= ["France","Germany","USA"]
    with open('your_file.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(list3))
```

But the output is horizontal instead of vertical and if anyone knows how to get rid of the quotation marks in the output I would appreciate that too.

Output with my above code: [image]

Output that I want:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a .csv file with values from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list)

Comment: CAn you post sample output? You want 3 lines with a country name on each line?

Comment: @ATOMP - If I read OP right, there should be 3 lines of output.

Comment: @tdelaney glad you answered this question. Linked this because it's basically the same question, and if no one decided to answer didn't want OP to still be stuck.

Comment: @ATOMP - your link is right 99% of the time but it writes a single row. I think OP wants 3 rows. It would be great if people writing questions added sample output, but hey, I guess they like to keep us guessing.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Python list, no `pandas` in sight.

```
In [26]: list3= ["France","Germany","USA"]
```

Look at what `str` produces:

```
In [27]: str(list3)                                                             
Out[27]: "['France', 'Germany', 'USA']"
```

That is one string with brackets and quotes.

What you want is more like:

```
In [28]: for word in list3: print(word)                                         
France
Germany
USA
```

Or writing the same to a file:

```
In [29]: with open('txt', 'w') as f: 
    ...:     for word in list3: 
    ...:         f.write('%s\n'%word) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [30]: cat txt                                                                
France
Germany
USA
```

Or with `print` `file` parameter:

```
In [31]: with open('txt', 'w') as f: 
    ...:     for word in list3: 
    ...:         print(word, file=f)
```

or you can join the strings newlines:

```
In [33]: '\n'.join(list3)                                                       
Out[33]: 'France\nGermany\nUSA'
In [34]: with open('txt', 'w') as f: 
    ...:     print('\n'.join(list3), file=f)
```

You could put the list in `pandas DataFrame`, but then you have to turn off columns and indices when writing the csv.

`numpy` also does it with `np.savetxt('txt',list3, fmt='%s')`.

Lots of ways of writing such a basic list of strings to a file.  Some basic, some using more powerful writers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the CSV module. Each row must be a list but you can generate them for the csv writer, one per item in your list

```
import csv
list3= ["France","Germany","USA"]
with open('your_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows([row] for row in list3)
```

Output

```
France
Germany
USA
```

You may not need the CSV module at all.  This will also write the list. The difference is that the first example would also escape internal quotes and commas, if that's a thing in your data.

```
import csv
list3= ["France","Germany","USA"]
with open('your_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(list3))
```