# Is there a way to export python list to a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have created a program to take inputs from user, later concatenate the data and send it to a list using append. I want to export the data from list to a .csv file, but don't know how to do it.Is there a way to do this? (Also I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS, and VS code)
Below is the list, and below that the data appended in the list :

```
Uploaded = []

upload =  number + " " + name + " " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " " + query + ":" + problem + " " + sign
Uploaded.append(upload)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

uploaded = []
number = 123
name = "Temp"
date = datetime.now()
query = 'selext * from temp;'
problem = "nothing"
uploaded.append([number, name, date, query, problem])
uploaded
```

`uploaded` List:

```
[[123,
  'Temp',
  datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 25, 16, 32, 5, 310469),
  'selext * from temp;',
  'nothing']]
```

Pandas `DataFrame` is the easiest way of converting list to csv

```
## create dataframe and save as csv    
pd.DataFrame(uploaded).to_csv("temp.csv",index=False)
```

Otherwise, you can use native [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) python module.

Comment: while using this, it shows pd as an undefined variable. What to do?

Comment: @SoumyaGoal you should do `import pandas as pd` if pandas not available in your `python`. Do install using `pip install pandas`

Comment: Thanks, did help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be helpful.

[Create a .csv file with values from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement it without any dependency:

```py
def list_to_csv(records, columns, dst_file):
  records_csv = [','.join(map(str, r)) for r in records]
  csv_text = '\n'.join(records_csv)
  with open(dst_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(csv_text)

records = [
  ['James', 13, 'Cat'],
  ['Karl', 20, 'Dog']
]

list_to_csv(records, columns=['name', 'age', 'pet'], dst_file='f.csv')
```

Also you can work with date times of any object that has the **str** method implemented.

Then, you can take a look at `f.csv` file.