# exporting list into a csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

first of all im still learning python and im having a good time so far. while learning I ran into this issue
I have a variable named MyList as follows

```
MyList = [{'orange', 'Lemon'},
 {'Apple', 'Banana', 'orange', 'Lemon'},
 {'Banana', 'Lemon'},
 {'Apple', 'orange'}]
```

I want to dump the list in a csv file in a rows as the same order as above so the csv will be like:

```
 orange   Lemon
 Apple    Banana   orange   Lemon 
 Banana   Lemon 
 Apple    orange
```

so I put the command bellow

```
MyList.to_csv("MyList.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

however it gives me the following error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the list object into csv object.

```
import csv

with open('MyList.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
     wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     wr.writerows(MyList)
```

Refer the following question by *Fortilan*
[Create a .csv file with values from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `csv` module and open a file for write:

```
import csv

MyList = [{'orange', 'Lemon'},
 {'Apple', 'Banana', 'orange', 'Lemon'},
 {'Banana', 'Lemon'},
 {'Apple', 'orange'}]

with open('MyList.csv', 'w') as f:
      
    # using csv.writer method from csv module
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows(MyList)
```