where to get requested list?
I have looked through stack overflow and found what I need - export of removed (banned) users from specific telegram chat (supergroup).
the number of removed/banned users around 5000.
I did this:
channel_id = -########
users = client.get_participants(client.get_input_entity(channel_id))
for user in users:
    if user.deleted:
        print(user)

and this:
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsKicked
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = #########
api_hash = '################################'
group_id = '-##############'
client = TelegramClient('apptitle', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    
    kicked_members = await client.get_participants(group_id, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked)
    for member in kicked_members:
        print(TipyWolf, 502264640)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())

But what next? Where should I get a file? Where do I have to look at output of these actions?
I try to wait and looked at root folder and there is nothing really.
I'm expecting to get a file like csv or just massive of data so I could just copy it.

You can get a file from the operating system by using the open() function. Is that what you mean?

if its a file with those 5000 banned \ removed TG accounts - then yes. i just need exported data about those 5000 banned accounts like username, ID

Your code doesn't create a file, it writes to the terminal. I think these may be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list

Can you point to a line or lines of code in your snippets you believe should generate a file on your filesystem?

No. Your code does not give you a file. And I cannot understand why that code wants to print TipyWolf a few thousand times.
. . .
   kicked_members = await client.get_participants(group_id, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked)

   # Define the file name
   file_name = 'kicked_members.txt'
   # Open the file in write mode ('w')
   with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
       for member in kicked_members:
       file.write(member + '\n')

I assumed member is a string holding usernames, adjust the file.write() if its not. The file would be in the same directory of the python file.

from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsKicked
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
api_id = #
api_hash = '#'
group_id = '-#'
client = TelegramClient('apptitle', api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
await client.start()
kicked_members = await client.get_participants(group_id, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked)
file_name = 'kicked_members.txt'
with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
for member in kicked_members:
file.write(member + '\n')
I run a find option in windows explorer to find a file kicked_members.txt but it found nothing :(
